# Is there a way to remove changes to a collection of committed files?

Tags: github

I have a PR on Github that has changes to Files A, B, C, D, E, F and G in it. I want to remove the changes I've made to files B, C, D and E. Is there an easy way to do it without manually going in and removing the differences via file compare?

Ideally, I'd want some kind of checklist where I could tick the files I want to revert the changes back to what they were before I changed anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undo commit action without auto-commit.
Then you can only commit the files you want to keep as modified from your previous commit

```
git revert <commit hash>
```